# Edit data in Entity framework code first model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

In the following code, i have country= 1, school=2 and course=3.
But after that when i am trying to assign that like,
userdata.UserCountry.CountryId= Convert.ToInt32(country). It says "Object reference is not set to .......instance of object" meaning null value.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Settings(FormCollection frm)
    {

            UsersContext db = new UsersContext();

            var userdata = db.UserDetails.Where(k => k.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).FirstOrDefault();

            string country = frm["UserCountry"]; // here I have 1.
            string school = frm["UserSchool"];
            string course = frm["UserCourse"];

            userdata.UserCountry.CountryId= Convert.ToInt32(country); // Here i have the null reference error.. !!
            userdata.UserSchool.SchoolId = Convert.ToInt32(school);
            userdata.UserCourse.CourseId = Convert.ToInt32(course);
            userdata.Link = frm["Link"];
            userdata.FullName = frm["FullName"];
            userdata.Email = frm["Email"];
            userdata.About = frm["About"];

            db.SaveChanges();

            return Content(Boolean.TrueString);
    }
```

this is the model:

```
public class UserDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Full name")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public bool? Verified { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="About")]
    public string About { get; set; }
    public virtual School UserSchool { get; set; }
    public virtual Course UserCourse { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public virtual Country UserCountry { get; set; }

}
```

Can anyone help me how to fix this ...plz.

Answer (score 1):

Try to include related entities in query result:

```
 var userdata = db.UserDetails
                  .Include("UserCountry")
                  .Include("UserSchool")
                  .Include("UserCourse")
                  .Where(k => k.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

BTW verify that you really have UserDetails with UserId you search for.

Comment: yes i have the userdetails with the uderid. I tried your code, still having the same error